How can I add custom user session config in classic Spring Framework web app?
I'm working on a classic Spring framework application that uses Spring-security-core 4.1.0.
I'm trying to add my user session config in a Spring Framework application but I cannot make it customizable.
I mean, in security.xml I can add the following general session-management config:
<session-management>
   <concurrency-control max-sessions="1">
   ...
</session-management>


... and it works. But I'd want to achieve enable or disable it, configure other max-sessions or similar without the need of rebuild the entire application.
My idea was to move this config to Java with:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SessionConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {...}


But this seems to be ignored. I found some info for Spring Boot, but that's not my scenario.
¿Could you help me, please? Thanks for your time.
I tried to move xml user session config to java with no success.
